# Why am I getting a fail to open stream?

Tags: php, relative-path, file-get-contents

I am getting fail to open stream at Warning: `file_get_contents(img/service/polaroid/pol_b1cfb94c5c28b8c2ffaa0db64132b700.png) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\XXX\class\service.php on line 18`

The image is stored at `/XXX/img/service/polaroid/pol_b1cfb94c5c28b8c2ffaa0db64132b700.png`.

PHP_SELF displays `/XXX/main.php`.

Can someone tell me what is wrong? I tried doing relative path `"../img/etc"` thinking because I am calling from the class folder, but that's not working as well.

```
$image = $row->pol_path;
        $image_data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
        $src='data: image/png;base64, '.$image_data;
```

Comment: Does PHP have the permissions to open the file? If not it will say: "Permission denied" somewhere in the error message.

Btw, what kind of a site are you running with the XXX root dir? :)

Comment: @Pintree, it has permission. The only error message is the one I pasted above.

Comment: @Pinetree You know it's pretty common to hide project specific names/details by using *** of XXX?

Comment: @LapMingLee I know, my juvenile brain just found it amusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$image_data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image, true));
```

OR

```
$image_data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH));
```

Comment: the second one works. i will accept the answer in 3 mins when it allows me. thanks @Sudhir

Answer (score 0):

If main.php is at XXX/main.php, and the image is at XXX/img/image.php, then the relative path would be './img/image.php'. You went above the root dir with the '../';